# Use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML variable, not HTML document?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a variable in my program that contains HTML data as a string.  The variable, `htmlText`, contains something like the following:

```
<ul><li><u>Mode selector </u></li><li><u>LAND ALT</u></li>
```

I'd like to iterate through this HTML, using the HtmlAgilityPack, but every example I see tries to load the HTML as a document.  I already have the HTML that I want to parse within the variable `htmlText`.  Can someone show me how to parse this, without loading it as a document?

The example I'm looking at right now looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
    }
}
```

I want to convert this to use my `htmlText` and find all `underline` elements within. I just don't want to load this as a document since I already have the HTML that I want to parse stored in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LoadHtml` method of `HtmlDocument` class

Comment: That did it.  As soon as the timer is up, you get the checkmark. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Document is simply a name, it's not really a document (or doesn't have to be).

```
var doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;
string myHTML = "<ul><li><u>Mode selector </u></li><li><u>LAND ALT</u></li>";
doc.LoadHtml(myHTML);
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")) {
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);

}
```

I've used this exact same thing to parse html chunks in variables.